# RedirectMatch 403 meaning?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a dedicated server and on it I have 200 websites all wordpress.
In my root folder I am looking at the .htaccess and see one phrase for one of my directories which holds a website, no other, just this one, with this:

RedirectMatch 403 angelgaragedoors

anyone know what this means?

should I be concerned? Its a live website

Answer (score 2):

This will direct any request including angelgaragedoors to get 403 Forbidden , for example if you write site.com/angelgaragedoors that will result 403 error and if you set in your `.haccess` that `ErrorDocument 403 /error403page.php` you will go directlly to `error403page.php`

you can add more than one word or pharses and for better understanding , visit to this link  http://www.wpstuffs.com/prevent-your-wordpress-blog-from-hackers-by-editing-htaccess/